# Windows not detected. OS fails to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, uefi

I have seen very similar topics and some solutions throughout the website. But I think none of the questions are asked along with enough details. So here I go.

I wanted to Install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS alongside with my Windows 8.1.
When I got to the Installation type, I had a message saying "There is no operating system detected" which I realized later on surfing the web about my problem (I'll get to the point soon). So I was like "I guess I have to check 'Something else', since it is the only option that doesn't erase information from my HDD". So I checked the radiobox and stepped into next step which is about resizing and partitioning just to see what appears (I didn't really want to install Ubuntu before backing up Windows). Like I said, I was curious and wanted to see what I was going to see.

[image]

Above link is a picture of the step that caused all the problems in my opinion. I changed the sizes, tried to figure  out the way it works, played with values and stuff, but, I never hit the "Install Now" button. I said "Okay it seems fair enough, I will install Ubuntu tomorrow after a little bit of research". I press QUIT and I want to get back to Windows 8.1. I take out the Ubuntu DVD and reboot the computer. This is where it gets messy. I am facing a problem where I get an error message says "EFI NETWORK 0 IPv4 and bla bla." So I start doing some research. I read all the related topics and the solutions were similar. Change the BIOS settings, disable UEFI mode, Enable security boot, disable security boot, check if HDD is detected or not and such. I tried everything. I spent 2 days trying to find right solution. So, clarify things, this is a simple explanation of what I think.

1-I think I am having this problem because I changed the way HDD works and tried to partition it without having that much of knowledge about it. Clearly, even though you don't press install, it actually partitions the hard drive.
2-I tried every possible solution, I still can't boot the PC. Here are the solutions I have tried so far:
     -Change BIOS boot settings(Enable/Disable UEFI,Legacy Support). When I boot UEFI enabled, I get "EFI Network 0 IPv4, No bootable device..." kinda problem. When I boot Legacy Support enabled, It says "no bootable device found, press any key to continue".
     -Check if HDD is detected(yes it is)
     -Start on safe mode(it fails to boot)
What I think is this:
I think there are 2 possible solutions left to try. First, take out your HDD, plug into any other computer, back up your information, then install Windows again. My second possible solution is to try booting windows with an OS-installed USB. So Would I be able to boot the PC if I try this?

My question is:
What is the real problem? Not having windows detected or having a broken HDD since I tried to partition it with no knowledge.

Another question is:
Is there any hope that I can save my HDD without having to erasing all the information I have. Is it possible to save informations from it?

My computer is a Lenovo Y410P. So it has a security start button right by the fan. I hit that button and choose "System recovery". Still fails to boot.

Additional important informations I forgot to mention:

- I said I didn't hit the Install Now button. Actually I did. But it failed giving me an error message saying something like this "mount point can't be the same bla bla". I am not quite sure what the message was but it had something to do with mounting. Simple put, it never started installing.
- I am able to boot my PC using "Try Ubuntu without Installing it" when I have the DVD placed in the driver.
- When I go to my system details on Ubuntu, I see this:

  [image]
- After having no hope at all and realizing that I had this problem because of partitioning, I went to Installation again. I thought If I had a good partition scheme, it would work. So I found a scheme and applied it on drivers. This time I hit the Install Now again, it asks me where I am from and which language I speak, showing a map of the world. So I see, it works, so I cancel installation before even starting it again.
- Having tried everything I could try (possibly I made it worse trying to fix it myself because of my curiosity) I thought it is best to seek assistance.
- If there is no hope left for me to save information from my HDD, I will just have to install Ubuntu and forget about Windows.

Sorry for giving you so many details. Probably, 50% of the information I gave you were either pointless or not needed. I tried to be clear as much as I can. Even though I tried my best, I know it is still confusing and you will be asking tons of questions as you try to realize the process. Well, please ask. I just want to save my information from my HDD. I don't really care about Windows.

Comment: You probably messed with your partitions and Windows can't find it. I suggest you to boot from Ubuntu LiveCD and select "Try Ubuntu without installing". Then open your File manager and check the drive to see if Windows is present. If it is present I can tell how to properly dual boot.

Comment: If you mean "Files" by "File Manager" I don't see anything related to Windows itself. Here's a picture of what I see.

http://imgur.com/ML5xpgL

All the partitioned drivers seems to be empty except the ones that have Ubuntu files.

Comment: Are there any Windows related files in 300gb volume. If possible please share image after opening 300gb volume and all other volumes after that I can say what is the exact problem.

Comment: There you go. Below is a link to all pictures I've just taken.

http://imgur.com/nnThq6L,dKnIONB,rLWb9gl,iMF0E6f,oy1nJ1S,x1c1xo7,MiYzO6L,uhJXmHg,I9xElM7

Comment: Okay you have completely messed up your system. It looks like you have formatted all the drives while trying to install Ubuntu. Its very hard to get your data back unless you have a backup of it. To boot into Ubuntu from bios select legacy mode or CSM from boot options. If that didn't work you have to use Windows DvD to install Windows or use Ubuntu CD to install Ubuntu as your only OS.

Comment: I have never created a back up before. Does Win8.1 happen to have back up points automaticly?

Comment: It doesn't create automatically. Moreover your drives are formatted so reinstalling OS is the only possible solution.

Comment: Ever since I lost all my informations on HDD, would you suggest installing Ubuntu?

Comment: It all depends on you want Ubuntu as your only operating system or do you want to dual boot with Windows.

Comment: If I boot Windows using a DVD, do you think would I still have my old informations in there? I formatted drivers, but on the other hand HDD is not damaged.

Comment: In the pictures you posted all the drives are empty which means you have formatted it. Once your drive is formatted it is hard to get your files back. I suggest you to install Windows then search for data recovery software. Using this software try to recover your data. You can't assume it recovers all your data but it tries its best.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thougt, Im not an expert but have you tried a live boot and going into the file manager to see if you can access your files from there

EDIT: Just boot from a live CD and then hit try Ubuntu, from there you can try to open the file manager just as you would a normal installation and try to access your windows files. It may not give you permission though.

Comment: I don't think I can. I don't know If there's a method getting to Windows files that I am not aware of. I am kinda new to Linux

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem rises due to grub error. When you install Ubuntu along side windows ,there cause some errors in boot loader. So you just need to insert windows disk and go to cmd prompt from repair.
 You will get grub error code handler from google search.
Then it will repair for you.

Comment: I'll try to do that as soon as I find a Windows CD/DVD or USB. That has been on my mind for a while now, too. Thank you sir.

Comment: It will surely work..

Comment: No doubts that I lost all my information that are on Windows?

Comment: No..your windows information will not change or get damaged. We are just repairing the bootloader.